# How to setup for loop with multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

This error is something to do with how I have set up the loop. The rest of the code has no impact on this problem.
[Here is the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSBHO.jpg)

## Draw competitors on the grid as per the provided data set

```
def random_moves(the_seed = None, max_rounds = 35):
    print('Here are the randomly-generated moves:')
    seed(the_seed)
    competitors = ['Competitor A', 'Competitor B', 'Competitor C', 'Competitor D',]
    shuffle(competitors)
    num_rounds = randint(0, max_rounds)
    moves = []
    for round_no in range(num_rounds):
        print()
        for competitor in competitors:
            move = [competitor, choice(['Left', 'Right', 'Up', 'Down'])]
            print(move)
            moves.append(move)
    print('\nThere were', len(competitors) * num_rounds,
          'moves generated in', num_rounds,
          ('round' if num_rounds == 1 else 'rounds'))
    return moves

def process_moves(random_moves):
    vertical = 90
    horizontal = 120
    position = [[-3*horizontal,3*vertical,'A',7],[3*horizontal,3*vertical,'G',7],[-3*horizontal,-3*vertical,'A',1],[3*horizontal,-3*vertical,'G',1]]
    penup()
    
    occupied = [[('A',7)],[('G',7)],[('A',1)],[('G',1)]] #To store the grid occupied
      
    pencolor('red')
    setpos(position[0][0],position[0][1])
    write('A',align='left',font=20)
    
    pencolor('blue')
    setpos(position[1][0],position[1][1])
    write('B',align='center',font=20)
    
    pencolor('green')
    setpos(position[2][0],position[2][1])
    write('C',align='center',font=20)
    
    pencolor('yellow')
    setpos(position[3][0],position[3][1])
    write('D',align='center',font=20)
      
for move in random_moves:
    competitor, direction = move[0],move[1]
    showturtle()
    if competitor == 'Competitor A':
        pencolor('red')
        if direction == 'Left':
            if position[0][2]=='A':
                continue
            else:
                position[0][0] = position[0][0] - horizontal
                position[0][2]=chr(ord(position[0][2])-1)
        elif direction == 'Right':
            if position[0][2]=='G':
                continue
```

Comment: you are unable to copy/paste or retype the error message in text

Comment: `for competitor, direction in random_moves():`, change `moves.append(move)` to `yield move` and remove `return moves`

Comment: What is the issue, have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: @AMC sry am new to coding but thanks for letting me know :D

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parenthesis in your call to `random_moves`.

Change this:

```
for move in random_moves:
```

To this:

```
for move in random_moves():
```

You may need to specify the parameters also.

Comment: ahh ok thanks so that is why I now get the error    if position[2][3]==7:
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable: IE: I have to define the parameters of the function so something like for move in random_moves(competitor, direction): Thanks for the help btw I'm new to coding :)